# Xcode 8.2.1 builds but doesn't run app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just updated to Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) in order to be able to work on my app and load it onto my iPhone 6 (iOS 10.2). However, every time I click to build and run the app, Xcode behaves exactly as it should, except the app never opens on my connected iPhone. I have also tested this in the simulator and it exhibits the same issue.

I have tried

- searching google and the rest of StackOverflow but all i could find was Xcode 8.2 bugs that were completely unrelated such as the cmd-R shortcut not working or other bugs that were not related.
- restarting Xcode and my phone
- restarting my mac
- cleaning the project
- cleaning the build folder

Xcode still alerts me when I try and build and run with my phone locked but when my phone is unlocked, nothing happens.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue? Can someone be so kind as to direct me to a workaround or something I can do so I can test my app?

**UPDATE:** i downloaded the zip from github and ran that and it worked... so i guess it was a problem with the project somehow...

Comment: Restart the Xcode

Comment: @azimov tried that. still nothing

Comment: have you tried cleaning project,removing derived data/cashes? sometimes it helps when i cannot run my program

Comment: @axel nope, nothing. updated the list with what i tried so far

Comment: are you able to run other projects?

Comment: @Axel strangely yes... my other iOS app works fine... thats really strange...

Comment: could it be an issue with the build settings?

Comment: now that i think if it, i was messing with provisioning profiles and the app identifier a while ago...

Comment: Ok I have 2 solutions (quick and slow):
1. quick - remove project everything, pull from remote repo and install pods,
2. it my be related (most likely) to schema of the project or xcode created some garbage in Library/Xcode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132136/discussion-between-developerace-and-axel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading a fresh .zip from the git repository, testing it, and having it work, I looked at the differences between the two project folders and concluded that it had something to do with the `.xcuserdata` files (which were being ignored in the repo). Apparently Xcode generates these for storing data like breakpoints and stuff like that.

So I moved the `xcuserdata` folder out of the project and re-ran it on my phone and it sow works as expected. I'm pretty sure now that this isn't a bug in Xcode and is just a result of me messing with stuff on another branch (which generated files in `xcuserdata` and somehow silently messed up the project when I switched back to the main branch.